# Remove certain languages from Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows, windows-7, sublimetext3

This is a duplicate of a question I put on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1532347/remove-certain-languages-from-sublime-text-3). But it may get answered here:

It was easy in Sublime text 2, but how do I remove (or limit the number) of code syntax files accessible on the bottom right hand corner.

[image: Sublime languages]

For example put Pascal into a folder when it's backed up, but not used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add packages to your `ignored_packages` user preference, and Sublime Text will ignore everything in those packages - including syntax definitions. There's no need to do any folder manipulations or backing up.

For example, to remove the Pascal syntax from the list:

```
// List any packages to ignore here. When removing entries from this list,
// a restart may be required if the package contains plugins.
"ignored_packages": ["Vintage", "Pascal"]
```